# data.table: avoid printing using `:=`

Tags: r, data.table

dt[,foo:="bar"] normally doesn't print anything to the terminal. But when in a script, and I source the script, it does. How can I avoid that? It also prints in package examples as shown by pkgdown which is really annoying. I think the same solution would apply in both cases.

Comment: If you need to suppress package loading print messages use `suppressPackageStartupMessages`

Comment: I don't understand the question.   if we use this reprex `x = data.table(1:5); writeLines('x[, foo:="bar"]',  (f <- tempfile())); source(f)` nothing gets printed to the console when we source.

Comment: youŕe right, dww. I wasn't smart enough to create a reproducible example as you did. I was confused by emacs' ess-load-file (C-c C-l) which I thought source()´d a file but actually loads it (which I don't know really know what means). Unfortunately, I can't provide a reproducible example of using pkgdown, but look at the example section here: shorturl.at/kmuU3